# Thymeleaf Page Layouts with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf, layout

I have several Thymeleaf templates that includes a common menu lateral template

```
  <div th:replace="tdk/common/menu :: [//div[@id='menu']]"></div>
```

I want to include to common javascript function in this common template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">


<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   

function repeatMe() {
           alert('lalala');
    }
    var interval = setInterval(function() { repeatMe(); }, 1000);
    repeatMe(); // To start it immediately

/*]]>*/
</script>
<div>
...
</div>
 </html>
```

But I realised that the Javascript is not included when I see the source code of the generated template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the script in the div element.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<div>

<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   

function repeatMe() {
       alert('lalala');
}
var interval = setInterval(function() { repeatMe(); }, 1000);
repeatMe(); // To start it immediately

/*]]>*/
</script>

</div>
</html>
```